# Adverb confusion

Tags: grammar, adverbs

> 同時に, 胸の奥を**ひやりと**冷たい手が撫でる

So in theory ひやりと is an adverb, which means it should be able to modify either 冷たい or 撫でる.

These are my interpretations of the sentence, considering the possibilities:

> 1)At the same time, a blood-curdlingly cold hand touched my heart
>
> 2)At the same time, a cold hand touched my heart, sending shivers down
> my spine

So what is it, and how can I tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the latter (2) is the better interpretation because *a)* ひやりと冷たい ("chillingly chilling") sounds fairly redundant in isolation, and *b)* most adverbs usually modify verbs.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.